# dhcpcd deleting gateway

Tags: iptables, routing, dhcp, gateway, dhcpcd

I'm trying to switch from DHCP to static IP by using dhcpcd.
When I switch from static to DHCP I'm configuring that eth0 (which used to have the static address) will also be the one with the DHCP address. But somehow dhcpcd seems to remove the gateway as well when it starts.

So if I originally have

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.50.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

It will become

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

This is my dhcpcd.conf file

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
#clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
#slaac private

# Configure IPv4 only
ipv4only

# Don't set any default routes
nogateway
# Allow the following interfaces
allowinterfaces eth0
```

I use `dhcpcd eth0` to request an IP

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which distribution is it ? in the dhcpd.conf you have an option nogateway ?

Comment: No, I added the nogateway to stop it from setting default gateway, didn't seem to work. The version is dhcpcd 7.1.0 and I'm running on an Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: Didn't manage to reproduce it with dhcpcd 9.4.1 . I keep both IPs and the default route . and the nogateway option has intended effect here: doesn't delete nor add the default route. I suspect it works fine because it sets promote_secondaries=1 , maybe your version doesn't and at some point all addresses disappear and so will the default route. Can you check `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries`? If it's 0,  what happens if you do first: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries=1` and try again? Does it work better then?

Comment: @A.B, sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries returns 1, but how do I install the 9.4.1 version? When I do a apt install dhcpcd it says dhcpcd package is not available and to install  dhcpcd5, which is how I got the 7.1.0  version

Comment: it's at least available in Debian 12